# Error while building Polyhedron demo

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, cgal

I was trying to build the Polyhedron demo from the CGAL library.

```
:~/Libs/demos/demo/Polyhedron$ cmake .
```

cmake gave no errors.

```
:~/Libs/demos/demo/Polyhedron$ make
```

make gave the following error:

```
[  0%] Automatic moc for target shortest_path_plugin
[  0%] Built target shortest_path_plugin_automoc
[  0%] Automatic moc for target demo_framework
[  0%] Built target demo_framework_automoc
[  1%] Automatic moc for target gl_splat
[  1%] Built target gl_splat_automoc
[  2%] Built target gl_splat
[  2%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/demo_framework.dir/Viewer.cpp.o
/home/param/Libs/demos/demo/Polyhedron/Viewer.cpp: In member function 
‘virtual void Viewer::setAntiAliasing(bool)’:
/home/param/Libs/demos/demo/Polyhedron/Viewer.cpp:76:12: error: 
‘updateGL’ was not declared in this scope
updateGL();
```

I am using:

- ubuntu 16.04
- QGLViewer 2.7.1
- Qt 5.6.2
- OpenGL version 3.0, OpenGL core profile version 4.5

Thank you.

Comment: What version of CGAL are you using?

Comment: Actually you are probably affected by the issues fixed by this [PR](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/2607)

Comment: @sloriot CGAL version 4.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The demo is experiencing problems with QGLViewer 2.7. You should use the previous verison (2.6.4) until the fix is integrated.

Comment: This fixed the make issue. However, I still get a segmentation fault when I run `$./Polyhedron_3`.

Comment: Are you using the proprietary drivers of your graphic card ? I know we had issues with MESA in the beginning of using Qt5, and CGAL 4.7 is getting pretty old